# R data.table: How to sum variables by group based on a condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate

Let's say I have the following R `data.table` (though I'm happy to work with base R, data.frame as well)

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(Category=c("First","First","First","Second","Third", "Third", "Second"), Frequency=c(10,15,5,2,14,20,3), times = c(0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1))

> dt
   Category Frequency times
1:    First        10     0
2:    First        15     0
3:    First         5     0
4:   Second         2     3
5:    Third        14     3
6:    Third        20     1
7:   Second         3     0
```

If I wished to sum the Frequencies by Category, I would use the following:

```
data[, sum(Frequency), by = Category]
```

However, let's say I wanted to sum `Frequency` by `Category` if and only if `times` is non-zero and not equal to `NA`?

How would one make this sum a conditional based on the values of a separate column?

EDIT: apologies for the obvious question. A quick addition: what about if the elements of a certain column are strings?

e.g.

```
> dt
   Category Frequency times
1:    First        ten    0
2:    First        ten    0
3:    First        five   0
4:   Second        five   3
5:    Third        five   3
6:    Third        five   1
7:   Second        ten    0
```

`Sum()` will not calculate the frequencies of `ten` versus `five`

Comment: Well, put your condition into data.table's i argument, obviously.

Comment: Test your code, which throws a warning. Also, show desired output -- it's not clear if you want groups for which no rows meet the condition or not.

Comment: I don't think it is correct to add another question after the fact... rather open a new question for that... but you need to convert the Frequency column into numeric before you do any math on it. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332463/convert-written-number-to-number-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember the logic of `data.table`: `dt[i, j, by]`, that is take `dt`, subset rows using `i`, then calculate `j` grouped by `by`.

```
dt[times != 0 & !is.na(times), sum(Frequency), by = Category]
   Category V1
1:   Second  2
2:    Third 34
```

Comment: Right. This makes sense now. Question: what if the column `Frequency` has elements type character?

Comment: Well then you can't use `sum()` unless you convert first into numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket subsetting to select only the rows with non-zero and non-NA values for `times` and then run your grouping operation.

```
dt[which(dt$times > 0)][, sum(Frequency), by = Category]
```

Comment: Question: what if the column Frequency has elements type character?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang how do you want your results to look?

Comment: I guess I'm describing expanding this data.table, such that there is a column of each categorical variable and the counts associated with it

Comment: You can reduce the first part of the chain to simply `dt[times > 0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use rowsum() for this.

**rowsum**

Give Column Sums of a Matrix or Data Frame, Based on a Grouping Variable

Compute column sums across rows of a numeric matrix-like object for each level of a grouping variable. rowsum is generic, with a method for data frames and a default method for vectors and matrices.

Keywords: manip

### Usage

```
rowsum(x, group, reorder = TRUE, …)
```

## S3 method for data.frame

```
rowsum(x, group, reorder = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE, …)
```

## S3 method for default

```
rowsum(x, group, reorder = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE, …)
```

Arguments
    a matrix, data frame or vector of numeric data. Missing values are allowed. A numeric vector will be treated as a column vector.
group

```
a vector or factor giving the grouping, with one element per row of x. Missing values will be treated as another group and a warning will be given.
```

reorder

```
if TRUE, then the result will be in order of sort(unique(group)), if FALSE, it will be in the order that groups were encountered.
```

na.rm

```
logical (TRUE or FALSE). Should NA (including NaN) values be discarded?

other arguments to be passed to or from methods
```

### Details

The default is to reorder the rows to agree with tapply as in the example below. Reordering should not add noticeably to the time except when there are very many distinct values of group and x has few columns.

The original function was written by Terry Therneau, but this is a new implementation using hashing that is much faster for large matrices.

To sum over all the rows of a matrix (ie, a single group) use colSums, which should be even faster.

For integer arguments, over/underflow in forming the sum results in NA.

### Value

A matrix or data frame containing the sums. There will be one row per unique value of