# R data transformation: create new rows based on numbers in different columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am searching for a solution how to transform the following data frame using dplyr:

```
item <- c('A','B','C')
one <- c(2, 1, 2)
two <- c(1,1,2)
data <- data.frame(item,one,two)
data
```

| item | one | two |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 2 |

Now, the column "one" contains the number of ratings of the value 1, the column "two" the number of ratings of the value 2. My ideal data frame after transformation would look like this:

| item | rating |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 2 |

Any idea how I could get to this output (it doesn't have to be dplyr)? I know how to use pivot_longer of the tidyr package but that doesn't solve the problem of repeating the number of rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
nums <- c(one = 1, two = 2, three = 3)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-item) %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarize(rating = rep(name, times = value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(rating = nums[rating])
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#   item  rating
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 A          1
# 2 A          1
# 3 A          2
# 4 B          1
# 5 B          2
# 6 C          1
# 7 C          1
# 8 C          2
# 9 C          2
```

I had to define `nums` because I couldn't find (in my haste) an easy way to convert `"one"` to `1` in a programmatic way. You'll need to make sure it goes out at least as far as you need; I added `three=3` for demonstration, if you truly only have `one` and `two` then you should be good as-is.

(Related to that topic: [Convert written number to number in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18332463/3358272))

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could convert it from wide to long format with the `gather()` function and then replace the string values of "one" and "two" by integers

```
library(tidyverse)
item <- c('A','B','C')
one <- c(2, 1, 2)
two <- c(1,1,2)
data <- data.frame(item,one,two)
long_df <- gather(data, rating, count, one:two)
new_df <- tibble()

for (i in range(nrow(data))) {
  new_df <- rbind(new_df, do.call("rbind", replicate(long_df[i, "count"], long_df, simplify = FALSE)))
}

new_df <- new_df %>% select(-c("count"))
```

Comment: (1) `gather`/`spread` are soft-deprecated, replaced by `pivot_longer`/`*_wider`, much more powerful for their intended use. (2) Iteratively `rbind`ing rows to a new frame works in concept but scales horribly and is discouraged in principle. See the [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), chapter 2 on "Growing Objects".

Comment: Thx, for the update!